# Which is the correct way to load a view/create a page in a GWT Java application

Tags: java, gwt

I am now going through my code to ensure it is correct and consistent. Straight way I find that I load a view in two different ways:
One is:

```
public HikeRecordView() {   

    //On load of page get the stored view data and create the page
    verticalPanel.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            if (event.isAttached()) {

                rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
                ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
                String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
                target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

                horizontalPanel_Existing.clear();
                verticalPanel.clear();

                AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataHandler<ViewData>(HikeRecordView.this);
                rpc.getViewData(callback);  
            }
        }
    });
    initWidget(verticalPanel);
}
```

And the other is:

```
public PackHolidayView() {  
    rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    //On load of page render the page
    verticalPanel.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            verticalPanel.clear();
            verticalPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

            //On load of page get the Account Level and ID of the account holder.
            AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataHandler<ViewData>(PackHolidayView.this);
            rpc.getViewData(callback);
        }
    });
    initWidget(verticalPanel);
}
```

They both seem to work so which is the best/recommended way to load a view please?

Comment: In the second option you will fire an RPC call twice - when you show the view and when you hide it.

Comment: I would suggest to use a MVP-pattern, to divide presentation and controlling code in two separate classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about splitting the code between Model, View and Presenter. Create appropriate layers. Consider using GIN for Dependency Injection.

Read an article located here: http://www.canoo.com/blog/2011/04/05/gwt-dependency-injection-recipes-using-gin/